# Google Adwords Conversion plugin

Tags: plugin-recommendation

Is there an available Google Adwords Conversion plugin for wordpress? I search high and low but can't find any.

Comment: What do you mean by Conversion?

Comment: The one that implements [this](https://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=86278)

Answer (score 2):

So simply log into your AdWords account, copy the code that is provided, and paste it in the footer.php file in your /wp-content/themes/THEMENAME folder.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Google AdWords site](https://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115794#):

> The Google code snippet will be provided when you sign up from the Conversions page located under the Reporting tab in your AdWords account. This code snippet can successfully track conversions when placed on the conversion page(s) of your site.

So simply log into your AdWords account, copy the code that is provided, and paste it in the footer.php file in your /wp-content/themes/THEMENAME folder.

Answer (score 1):

Placing an AdWords conversion script in a WordPress site's footer would result in over-reporting.  I believe he's looking to just place this code on the "thank-you / conversion" page.

[Creative Clans Embed Script](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/creative-clans-embed-script/) can place scripts on individual pages. Or, you could create a custom page template and hard code the script on that page.